# Structuring Database First model classes with MVVM in WPF App

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am following [this](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/wpf-mvvm-entity-framework-app/table-of-contents) course on integrating an MVVM architecture with an WPF app, but using code first. For my own app I am using database first, with only a
few tables.

This is my project structure, with the 3 layers, Model-View-ViewModel. In the course he creates two model classes, of course using code first in the model project, while the Data Access project handles migrations and the DbContext.

[image]

Now, when I use Database First, EF creates all the model classes for me, but the database context is included as well. My edmx is structured like this:

[image]

My question is what I need to place in which project? I'm aware that I have my view models in the UI project, which then use a data service to create a new context, but it seems I can do this all in the UI project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is what I need to place in which project?

The entity classes go in the model project and the `DbContext` belongs to the data access layer.

You should be able to move the `Nolek.tt` file to the model projecy by doing the following.

- Open File Explorer (right-click on the solution in Visual Studio and choose the “Open Folder in File Explorer” option) and move the `Nolek.tt` file to the model project folder.
- Back in Visual Studio, include the `Nolek.tt` file in the model project by clicking on the “Show All Files” icon at the top of the Solution Explorer and then right-click on the `Nolek.tt` file and choose the “Include In Project” option.
- Delete the `Nolek.tt` file from the DAL project.

For the template in the model project to be able to find the model you then need to modify it to point to the correct EDMX path. You can do this by setting the `inputFile` variable in the `Nolek.tt` template file to point to an explicit path where to find the model:

```
const string inputFile = @"../NolekWPF.DataAccess/Nolek.edmx";
```

Once you save the file, the entity classes should be generated in the model project.

Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/

Comment: Thanks very much! The blog you linked just links back to this post by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would keep everything in the same project, separated by namespaces (folders) for each distinct area.

In my own project I have a UI folder for Views and ViewModels, then a separate folder for Models and a bunch of other folders for things such as helper classes.

Comment: Yes, but using namespaces instead of assemblies makes violations of the design go unnoticed.